# How to store arrays in an array and to do comparision

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 unsigned char a[3];
 unsigned char b[3];
 int *l[3]=NULL;
 int i = 0;

 a[0]=0;
 a[1]=1;
 a[2]=2;
 b[0]=3;
 b[1]=4;
 b[2]=5;

 l[0]=&a;
 l[1]=&b;
 if(strcmp(l[0],l[1])==0) {
   printf("Compared not same");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I want to store the arrays inside an array "l".And to do the comparision of the array stored at index 0 and at index 1.
I am getting errors . please help.

Comment: too many errors, please get a C book.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 unsigned char a[3];
 unsigned char b[3];
 unsigned char *l[2];

 a[0] = 0; a[1] = 1; a[2] = 2;
 b[0] = 3; b[1] = 4; b[2] = 5;

 l[0] = a; l[1] = b;
 if(strncmp(l[0], l[1], 3) != 0) {
   printf("Compared not same");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code will make an error with a = [0, 1, 2] and b = [0, 4, 5]. It will say that they are equal. Also, VS 10 shows error C2664: 'strncmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'const char *':"

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  unsigned char a[3];
  unsigned char b[3];
  unsigned char *l[2];

  a[0] = '3'; a[1] = '4'; a[2] = '\0';
  b[0] = '3'; b[1] = '4'; b[2] = '\0';

  l[0] = a; l[1] = b;
  if(strcmp(l[0], l[1]) != 0) {
    printf("Compared not same");
  } else {
    printf("Compared same");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    char a[3] = {1, 1, 2};
    char b[3] = {1, 4, 5};
    char *l[2]= {a, b};

    printf( (strncmp(l[0], l[1], 3)==0) ? "Compared are equal" : "Compared are not equal");

 return 0;
}
```

And note, that 0 is the end of the line, so as arrays of chars [0, 1, 2] and [0, 5, 5] are equal. Also, if you don't have a 0 in such array, it may cause an errors because it will be endless array and will try to get values from memory that is not for this array. You really should start with any good c/c++ book about basics of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about *storing arrays in an array*, but you should use `memcmp` instead of `strcmp` to compare arrays (because `strcmp` compares strings, and your arrays are not strings).

```
 unsigned char a[3];
 unsigned char b[3];
 unsigned char *l[2]; // note: corrected a few errors in this line
 int i = 0;

 a[0]=0;
 a[1]=1;
 a[2]=2;
 b[0]=3;
 b[1]=4;
 b[2]=5;

 l[0]=a;
 l[1]=b;
 if(memcmp(l[0],l[1], sizeof(a))==0) { // note: have to specify the length
   printf("Compared same"); // note: reveresed the logic
 }
```